# delete verbatimtextOutput

Tags: r, shiny

ran into this weird issue when teaching a student about shiny programming.

What i wanted was to make code that deletes the verbatimtextOuput element, rather than print an empty value

This is the code he wrote, but it deletes all buttons, the whole UI basically. Can this be done? I know more complex options like conditional panels etc, but just trying to figure out why removeUI doesn't do what I expected here.

Thanks!

app:

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(  h5("Hello there"),      #First text on the window
               br(),                            #empty line
               actionButton(inputId = "ClickonMe", label = "Make data"),  # button 1
               actionButton(inputId = "ClickonMe2", label = "Print data"), # button 2
               actionButton(inputId = "ClickonMe3", label = "Transform data"),

               verbatimTextOutput("Response_text")  #reactive text output    )

server <- function(input,output) {
     values <- reactiveValues()
     observeEvent(input$ClickonMe,
               values$name <- TRUE   )
     observeEvent(input$ClickonMe3,
               if (values$name == TRUE) { values$name <- FALSE}
               else { values$name <- TRUE}   )
     observeEvent(input$ClickonMe2,
               if (values$name == TRUE) { output$Response_text <- renderPrint( isolate({values$name}) ) }
               else  if (values$name == FALSE)  {  removeUI(
                 selector = "div:has(> #Response_text)"
               )
               }

  )    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT VERSION:**

changed pork chops answer a little so that this version removes and remakes the verbatim element in the ui. 
What i now try to fully understand is, is why the piece req(....) has such an impact. the print(values$name) proofs that the variable exist, and the observer sees it, yet if you # the req( ) line, suddenly the app stops recreating the verbatimtextouput after it has been removed the first time. 
Hope I can learn why this is the case. Thank you!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(  
  h5("Hello there"),                                          # First text on the window
  br(),                                                       # empty line
  actionButton(inputId = "ClickonMe", label = "Make data"),   # button 1
  actionButton(inputId = "ClickonMe2", label = "Print data"), # button 2
  actionButton(inputId = "ClickonMe3", label = "Transform data"),
  mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("Response_text"))
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$name <- T

  observeEvent(input$ClickonMe,{
    values$name <- T 
  })

  observeEvent(input$ClickonMe3,{
    if (values$name){ values$name <- F}
    else{ values$name <- T }
  })

  observeEvent(input$ClickonMe2,{

    print(values$name)
  output$Response_text <- renderPrint({ isolate({ 

    req(values$name)
    if(!values$name){
      removeUI(
        selector = "div:has(> #Response_text)"
      )
    }else {
    as.character(values$name)}
  })
      })

})
}
```

Comment: I think you need some teaching too as there are loads of issues with your code!

Comment: Ok, 1st thanks for the answer, 2nd I know I am far from perfect, still learning and tought all of it myself, so I code in strange ways sometimes. This was a simple mistake, my version had the brackets, my students version didn't.    To be honest, I didn't spot that his code didn't have the curly brackets in them, YES you need those indeed, I always use them

Comment: @Ben, hey thanks for the link. I wouldn't go as far as calling it teaching. I'm still too much a learner myself, but I have to show my colleague how my code works in the program I am building

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) First of all please have a look at the [Google's R Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml) when writing code and try to stick to it I think both you and your students will benefit from it.

2) Use curly braces too when using functions such as `observeEvent` and `renderPrint`

3) Familiarise yourself with `req` function which is very handy

Sample Code how to remove UI:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(  
  h5("Hello there"),                                          # First text on the window
  br(),                                                       # empty line
  actionButton(inputId = "ClickonMe", label = "Make data"),   # button 1
  actionButton(inputId = "ClickonMe2", label = "Print data"), # button 2
  actionButton(inputId = "ClickonMe3", label = "Transform data"),
  mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("Response_text"))
)

server <- function(input,output,session) {
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$name <- NULL

  observeEvent(input$ClickonMe,{
    values$name <- T 
  })

  observeEvent(input$ClickonMe3,{
    if (values$name){ 
      values$name <- F}
    else{
      values$name <- T
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$ClickonMe2,{
    if (values$name){ 
      values$name <- F
      }
    else{
      values$name <- T
    }
  })

  output$Response_text <- renderPrint({
    req(values$name)
    if(!values$name){
      removeUI(
        selector = "div:has(> #Response_text)"
      )
    }
    as.character(values$name)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for for ```req```. Is it similar to ```stopifnot()```?

Comment: `stopifnot` evaluates each of your supplied expressions, and then checks that all of them are TRUE which might stop the shinyapps. `req` on the other hand is of type `"try-error"` class which should catch your errors

Comment: I will definitely study the style rules though, looks great. I am an autodidact when it comes to coding, and am still learning to do things "the right' way here and there. 
Your answer has the same code under observeEvent for clickonme2 and clickonme3, changed that to run it. 
I know about req to make sure a variable is there, stop if not. What I don't understand in this case is this: values$name exists as soon as server is made (especially if coded as values$name <- T instead of NULL) yet the app won't work without it. Can you explain why that is Pork Chop?  (see new app in edit of question